# Why is it necessary to temporarily save keys to a list when iterating over a dictionary's items and modifying their values?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1167089/4385532):

```
foreach (var key in dict.Keys.ToList())
{
    dict[key] = false;
}
```

> The call to ToList() makes this work, since it's pulling out and (temporarily) saving the list of keys, so the iteration works.

Why is the call to `ToList()` necessary here?

We're modifying values, not keys, and, to my best understanding, only modyfying the set of keys of a dictionary would break iteration over keys. In particular - to my, likely wrong understanding - the ordering of keys can only change if we are adding or removing items from a dictionary, which we are not doing.

Answer (score 5):

If you [read the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,fd1acf96113fbda9,references) for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Insert`, you will see it is incrementing the `version` field which drives the guards while enumerating collections.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have internal version numbers.

Setting a value in a dictionary updates its version number which will have the same effect as modifying an enumerated collection in a foreach loop.

Comment: A reference to that info would be good

Comment: Daniel beat me to it. Also, possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070766/editing-dictionary-values-in-a-foreach-loop?rq=1